# Can I pronounce a "t" as a glottal stop in the word "Netflix"

Tags: pronunciation

I am talking American English now. Usually when a "t" comes at the end of the word "wheat" or before "n" or "m" sounds as in "mountain" and "treatment", the t sound is not pronounced and i pronounced as a glottal stop instead. Can I do the same with the word "netflix"?

Comment: Yes. The /t/ would go, except for an optional gloʔʔal stop.

Comment: @JohnLawler You mean you could pronounce it or it could have a gloʔʔl no? You can't say /nɛflɪks/ in Gen Am can you?

Comment: I can't, at any rate. The usual fate of /t/ before a cluster in my speech is to become [ʔ].

Comment: Yes, t can be glottal stop before a consonant, and the f following the t is a consonant.  (It's not before a "cluster" that it happens, John.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In certain parts of America (but not all), you can use a glottal stop for a  *t* in Netflix, as well as many double t's (kitten, button), terminal t's (but, net, fit, cat, pet, cot, bought). This will net you some strange looks in your travels, though. Being from New England originally, this was standard to my ear, but I had to change it as I moved around because of the unwanted attention it called to itself. If you can avoid it, it might to be to your benefit; those who use glottal stops will hardly notice it, and those who hear *t's* will find your English good.

Comment: It's very common before syllabic 'n', as in *kitten*, and I don't think it would be unusual in *Netflix*. My impression is that it is unusual in much of the U.S. at the ends of words, like *but, net, fit, cat*.

Comment: I live in Washington and it's just jarring whenever I hear someone use a glottal stop for a 't'. I pronounce kitten... kit-ten whereas ki'un sounds weird like the person forgot there was a 't' in the word or refused to pronounce it for religious reasons. In one episode of TMZ, a reporter used the glottal stop 't' and Harvey stopped the show until she pronounced it with the 't' intact.

Comment: I don't know, I use a small or soft glottal stop in kitten. Not to do so sounds odd to me, no matter what part of the US you're from: almost like "kiddin'" short for kidding. Or else you really do make the double-t: kit-tin, which sounds like someone is badly attempting a posh English accent. Sure, it's not a full Cockney glottal, but there is definitely some stopping at the back of the throat before moving to the n-sound. What @Peter Shor says sounds right to me.

Comment: It's t before a consonant that becomes glottal stop, for General American.  Not "double t" (which is only double in the spelling), and not "terminal" t (unless the next word begins with a consonant).

Comment: @medica, sound changes depend on surrounding sounds, not surrounding letters.  There is only one [t] in your example words, not two, and the following *sound* is a consonant, not a vowel: it's a syllabic [n].  So this [t] is subject to replacement by glottal stop.  I'm from Ohio, and I do have glottal stop in "kitten button flatten", etc.  I just wrote out a more thorough description of how glottal stop gets into these words, in case you're interested; see my answer here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14666/can-you-explain-glottal-stop

Comment: @Greg Lee- Do vowel sounds count? *The Cat in the Hat* has two glottal t's for a lot of people. So does "part on" in many parts of the US. I'm not a linguist, but I have ears. And I don't understand your hard and fast rules.

Comment: @medica For your example "The Cat in the Hat", I accept that the [t] of "Cat" can be replaced by glottal stop, provided that the following word "in" is pronounced as a consonant -- syllabic [n].  That follows the rule I gave.  However, replacing the "t" of "Hat" does not follow my rule, since nothing follows.  Maybe it happens for you, but I'd have to be convinced.  My rules are not "hard and fast", but they characterize the varieties of American English that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @GregLee - I thought you might say the next sound was the consonant *n*, but you wrote consonant, then ignore the vowel or the full stop. Your argument is based on definitions of which I'm unaware (and therefore can't anticipate or make a case for my position.) I can drop it here. (In my mind just now, that *t* is glottal, too. As I said, I'm not a linguist. I'm sure you have a definition for the hissed h sound I don't know.)

Comment: @medica, I'm trying to follow what you're saying.  I don't know what "ignore the vowel or the full stop" refers to.  Which example?  You mean the "cat in" part?  If it works like my speech, "in" has several possible pronunciations, with or without a vowel.  Syllabic [n] is possible, in which case there is no vowel following "cat".  It's also possible to pronounce "in" with a vowel.  As I understand the facts, if "in" is pronounced with a vowel, the preceding [t] will *not* be replaced by glottal stop (instead, probably, it will be replaced by a flap). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) ...   If "in" is pronounced without a vowel, then preceding [t] will be replaced by glottal stop.  In any event, it all depends on the pronunciation and not the spelling.

Comment: @GregLee - I appreciate the attempt to understand what I'm trying to say, but I think we'll have difficulty explaining things because we have different vocabularies: yours is a linguist's, mine is a layperson's. I would answer that pronunciation usually follows spelling to a degree, but I agree with you that "it all depends on the pronunciation and not the spelling." My first language was French; I didn't learn English until I went to school. I remember my classmates' chuckles when I first encountered *colonel* and *Yosemite* (I pronounced it *Yoʊz'-mait*.)

Answer (score 2):

The specific environments in which /t/ can become [ʔ] in english varies slightly from dialect to dialect. At the beginnings of words /t/ almost always becomes [tʰ]. In dialects without [ʔ] or [ɾ], the sound almost always remains [t] anywhere else. Before a consonant or before a pause in speach, /t/ may become [ʔ]. However, in between vowels is more complicated. Some dialects will use [ɾ], while others use [ʔ]. This has lead to homophones between "latter" and "ladder" as /d/ can become [ɾ] in any environment other than at the start of a word.