# the omitted "t" sound

Tags: pronunciation

My English teacher told me that some native speakers omit the /t/ sound in some words, for example, writ't'en, Bri't'ain, impor't'ant. That means before pronouncing the /t/, there is a sudden pause and then go for /ː(ə)nt/.Is that true?
Thank you so much :)

[maybe there is no such a thing. But when I listen to BBC radio, someone says "Britain", I can hardly hear /t/ when they say that word. Why they pronounce that way?]

Comment: There is no “omitted *t”* because /t/ is a phoneme, not a sound. Its possible sounds range from nothing at all to sounds like [tʰ], [t], [t̞],  [t̪ ], [ɾ], and [ʔ] — amongst others. The last is the glottal stop you allude to. See related and possible dupes http://english.stackexchange.com/q/216741  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21681 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/198586 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/159463 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110741 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/236607 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/105011 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102624

Comment: No, that's not true. What actually happens is that there is a glottal stop [ʔ] allophone of /t/ that often occurs between a stressed vowel and an unstressed one, (like all the examples you present). Thus, _bottle_ /batl/ would be pronounced ['baʔḷ]. Your teacher probly didn't know the name for glottal stop (mnemonic: ['glɔʔḷ stɔp]), which is the sound separating the vowels in "Uh-oh!" ['ʔəʔo] and occurs as a consonant phoneme in many languages.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/how-should-often-be-pronounced

Comment: Please just look at John Lawler's comment above and ignore the two answers given so far.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Newsreaders speak more slowly and also tend to accentuate their speech, especially when they are speaking to a diverse audience.

I am a native speaker and if I were to pronounce Britain on its own, I would pronounce the "t" quite clearly. If I were to pronounce it in a sentence, the "t" would be a lot more subtle. If I was speaking to an international audience, I'd imagine I'd make more of an effort to pronounce the "t", but this might well be down to the fact that I would be speaking more slowly.

Pronouncing the "Br" in Britain requires the speaker to push a lot of air from their mouth. In order to give the "t" an equal amount of focus in the word "Britain", the speaker would be forced to pause slightly before its pronunciation. Since we typically like to speak quickly, we don't bother with the short pause and pronounce the "t" with less focus instead.

It is common in languages for certain letters in certain words to loose their accentuation over time. This is because people can still understand what word they are referring to even if this letter looses focus. This is  why silent letters appear in the spelling of certain words. For example in Old English, the "k" was pronounced in "know", as was the "g" in "gnaw".

Comment: I don't think the 'br' at the start of 'Britain' has anything to do with it.  Compare 'cotton', in which I [a UK native] also use the glottal-stop variant of the /t/ phoneme.

Comment: David Garner If speaking quickly, I pronounce "cotton" by blowing out more heavily on the "co", resulting in the fact that I dont have enough energy left to accentuate the "tt" to the same extent. Please note that I dont have a UK accent.

Comment: Sorry, @Baz, I don't accept that.  Compare 'batten' and 'rotten'  -  no 'heavy blowing', as you put it, at the start of those words.  It's about the /t/ following a vowel and preceding a syllabic /n/.

Comment: @David Garner I would pronounce the tt in batten more clearly than usual, but almost not at all in rotten. :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept your teacher gave you is absolutely right.  Your teacher's *way* of explaining it might not pass muster with some of the experts who participate here at English Language & Usage, but that's okay.

I think your teacher was probably motivated by wanting to help you understand people better in authentic verbal communication.

There is always a natural variation in pronunciation, among individuals, and also across regions and socio-economic classes.

For you, as a non-native speaker of English, it would be best to use as clear a pronunciation as possible, to maximize people's ease in understanding you.  So I would encourage you to always pronounce the T clearly in *Britain*.